# Using a `mysql_query` to insert category values

Tags: mysql

Ok I'm importing direct from a csv to MySQL, using a `mysql_query` to insert values.
How do you insert category terms into the Wordpress database structure assigning them to a post. Below are two import queries- you will see `INSERT INTO wp_terms` which I know is not correct, but need help fixing. The rest of the code works beautifully.

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

    $cn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','1');
    mysql_select_db('bitnami_wordpress',$cn);
    $path = "hotels.csv"; // SET YOUR CSV FILE PATH HERE
    $row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen($path, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 100000000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
            $row++;
            $data_entries[] = $data ;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    $final_data = array();
    $count = 0 ;
    array_shift($data_entries);
    foreach ($data_entries as $value) {
        $temp = implode('', $value);
        $tempArr = explode('|', $temp);
        $final_data[] = $tempArr;
        $ins_str = "INSERT INTO wp_posts values('','','','','".mysql_real_escape_string($tempArr[27])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($tempArr[1])."','','".mysql_real_escape_string($tempArr[18])."','','','','".mysql_real_escape_string($tempArr[2])."','','','','','','','','','".mysql_real_escape_string($tempArr[17])."','','')";
        mysql_query($ins_str,$cn);
        $post_id = mysql_insert_id($cn);

        $ins_str = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta VALUES('','".$post_id."','list-id','".$tempArr[0]."')";
        mysql_query($ins_str,$cn);
        $ins_str = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta VALUES('','".$post_id."','airport_code','".$tempArr[3]."')";
        mysql_query($ins_str,$cn);
        $ins_str = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta VALUES('','".$post_id."','location','".$tempArr[4]."')";
        mysql_query($ins_str,$cn);
        $ins_str = "INSERT INTO wp_terms VALUES('','".$post_id."','job_listing_region','".$tempArr[5]."')";
        mysql_query($ins_str,$cn);
        $ins_str = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta VALUES('','".$post_id."','low_rate','".$tempArr[13]."')";
        mysql_query($ins_str,$cn);
        $ins_str = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta VALUES('','".$post_id."','high_rate','".$tempArr[14]."')";
        mysql_query($ins_str,$cn);
        $ins_str = "INSERT INTO wp_postmeta VALUES('','".$post_id."','confidence','".$tempArr[15]."')";
        mysql_query($ins_str,$cn);
        $ins_str = "INSERT INTO wp_terms VALUES('','".$post_id."','job_listing_category','".$tempArr[16]."')";
        mysql_query($ins_str,$cn);

    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($final_data);
?>
```

Thanks in advance, Murray

Comment: What error are you getting or what incorrect data is being inserted? Have you considered using MySQL's CSV engine?

Comment: At the moment the data is being inserted as a custom field in `wp_postmeta`. What I would like is to create category terms under a custom category i.e. `job_listing_region`. Will check MySQL's CSV engine.

Comment: What is the result of printing out $ins_str after the "INSERT INTO wp_terms..." line? I have to tell you, I know virtually nothing about PHP, but the result of the ins_str plus the DDL of wp_terms should start to give us a clue. You haven't said what the error you're getting is!

Comment: Have you tried http://wordpress.stackexchange.com ???

Comment: After having a good look around I found this post on Wordpress Stack Exchange, though still mind boggled.. will ask questions over there. Thanks :) http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139221/sql-to-update-custom-post-taxonomies